# React Native reload components after language change

Tags: reactjs, react-native, reload

How can I reload all components in the page because I need to navigate to another page and back to the same page to see everything updated , I tried to use react-native-restart but it didnt work.
I need it to work on all platforms
thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by reloading components after language change. I guess you want multiple language support in your application. If yes, then you could use [react-i18next](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next) library.

Comment: example: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/master/example/react-native/App.js

Comment: I already got language support , but after changing language some components and icons wont update their location to ltr(left side) and it looks like I need to reload them how can I do it